# Get todays date a year ago

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a script where I need today date but from a year ago, however I also need it to be in the following format with the time.

```
 2017-11-07 00:00:00.000
```

I currently have got to a place where I have last years date just not the 00:00:00.000 timestamp.

```
select  DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE())
```

This returns the time of the time the query was ran.

```
 2017-11-07 13:37:10.770
```

This is for a where clause as I need to get some data from today's date from last year so looking for a where clause that starts at this date last year at midnight and finishes at 23:00:00.000

It's for a client running SQL Server 2005.

Comment: Sql Server 2005 is no longer supported. In fact, extended support for 2008 is about to end soon - So you better tell your client they should upgrade to a modern version of SQL Server.\

Comment: Customer has been told. However I do not manage their IT budget or projects.

Comment: Have you given any thought about how leap years should play into this? What if today's date a year ago didn't exist? Does it matter if Yesterday's date a year ago was two days before today's date a year ago? Etc.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever agree with your point however we have been informed this is a 6 month solution until a new reporting tool is implemented. So we should not need to worry about that

Comment: Yes, they clearly don't let things linger around far longer than they ought to :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using:

```
CONVERT(DateTime, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE())))
```

Here is a query to see this in action:

```
SELECT
    GETDATE() AS today,
    DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE()) AS today_last_year,  -- what you already have
    CONVERT(DateTime, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE()))) AS
        today_last_year_midnight;
```

This returned (as of the time of writing this answer):

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly and idea how I would set it at the other end to 23:00:00.000

Comment: @ThisIsLegend1016: `SELECT DATEADD(hour, 23, DATEADD(d,0,DATEDIFF(d,0, DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE()))))`. SQL can be so "readable"

Comment: @ThisIsLegend1016, I'm glad you found your answer. Please take a moment to mark this as your accepted answer by clicking the gray check mark to the left of the answer. It lets other users know the question has an answer, and rewards the user who answered with some reputation points. And you get some, too.